# Problems with Geth after installing Parity

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

I used to run a node on my Mac by simply typing `geth console` on the cli. However, I had to stop running `geth` about a month ago when the DOS attacks started. Last week though, I downloaded and installed Parity and I run it by typing `parity --geth` on the cli. But now, when I try to run `geth` using the old way (i.e. by typing `geth console`), I get an error message. When I go into my Mist folder, I don't see `geth` in there anymore. There is a `geth` in the Parity folder though. So I downloaded the latest version of `geth` and it's sitting in my Application folder, and I can't seem to run it from the cli like before. Could you please let me know what I need to do so that I can run `geth` exactly as I had before and where I should move the `geth` executable file to as it is sitting in my Applications folder?

Comment: what is the message error do you get?

Comment: I'm not getting an error now for some reason.  Now it just says "Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!" and below the prompt ">" shows up but just hangs there.  Nothing happens.  What to do?

Answer (score 2):

don't worry just [re-download](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases) geth without Mist. [add](http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/) the folder where you put it into the Path.
don't run geth alongside parity. run `parity --geth` (Geth-IPC-compatibility mode) first and use `**geth attach**` to get a console to execute your scripts and commands.

Comment: I did what you suggested and maybe I did something wrong because after I add the folder to the Path and typed "geth console" in the cli, I got:

Comment: fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0xb01dfacedebac1e pc=0x4027bab]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x4d93f00, 0x2a)
 /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:547 +0x90
runtime.sigpanic()
 /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:12 +0x5a
runtime.unlock(0x540d220)
 /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/lock_sema.go:107 +0x14b
runtime.(*mheap).freeSpan.func1()
 /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.go:726 +0x186
runtime.systemstack(0x7000028f0b30)

Comment: The output was a lot longer but it went over my allotted character limit...

Comment: tried it again and block synchronization started.  bizarre...  now it hangs again so back to square one.

Comment: check if you run of space...or something related